# gmpy2 installation error in vs code in pytho 39

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, python-wheel, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

*tried instaliing microsoft visual studio still notinstalled*
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gmpy2'
PS C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\sem1\fcs\Assignment 1> pip install gmpy2
Collecting gmpy2
Using cached gmpy2-2.0.8.zip (280 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: gmpy2
Building wheel for gmpy2 (setup.py) ... error

[image]

Tried installing gmpy2 but was unable to
all errors have been shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of gmpy2.

Unfortunately, it's rather complicated to build gmpy2 from source. I have published pre-compiled versions for next major release. But they are not chosen by default when you try to install gmpy2. You can install the release candidate with the command:

pip install gmpy2==2.1.0rc1

The command may differ slightly depending on the exact configuration of your system.

Please let us know if you are still getting errors.